Recovering an old wallet created using dice rolls
Years ago in 2016 I created a wallet to pay off some hackers that hacked a friend's PC. There was some small change left, most of which I sold, but I think there's still some BTC there that might be worth a few hundred dollars.
The problem is, I have since uninstalled the app I used (mycellium wallet) and the only thing I have in the way of backup is a list of numbers which represent dice rolls I used to generate the wallet. The list is 12 sets of 6 rolls of a 6-sided die. So something like:
246523
123346
..(12 lines total, 72 numbers)
I searched for some common method to derive a wallet using 72 dice rolls and I'm not coming up with anything. BIP39 uses a 12 word phrase but there is no dice method involving 72 throws to derive it that I can find.. Anyone have an idea what method it might have been? It was back in 2016.
